# How can I create this complicated SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I’m using Active Record now. But it’s too slow if this code runs.

```
@communities = current_user.get_up_voted(Community)
@codes = Code.includes(:user).where(:community_id => @communities.collect(&:id)).order("users.active_at DESC").page(params[:page])
```

So, I’d like better performance with direct SQL query. But I have no idea how to write such complicated condition.
How can I write SQL query to make this sophisticated and fast?

How do you write SQL query for this condition?

There are 4 tables such as below

1. Users

   - id
   - active_at(date time)
2. Votes

   - votable_id (this links to community.id)
   - voter_id (the id of user who bookmarked)
   - vote_flag (this has to be 1)
3. Community

   - id
4. Codes

   - community_id (this links to community.id)
   - user_id (this links to a user who created a code record)

User can bookmark Community by updating vote_flag of Votes table.

I’d like to fetch all the codes that belongs to communities that current_user has already bookmarked, and they have to be sorted by ‘user.active_at’ column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `JOIN` all those 4 tables and use `ORDER BY` to sort the records..

```
SELECT * FROM Users, Votes, Community, Codes 
WHERE Codes.community_id = Community_id 
AND Codes.user_id = Users.id
AND Votes.votable_id = Community.id
AND Votes.voter_id = Users.id
AND Votes.votable_id = Codes.community_id
AND Votes.voter_id = Codes.user_id
AND Votes.vote_flag = 1
ORDER BY USERS.active_at ASC
```

OR, for more readability:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
JOIN Codes ON Codes.user_id = Users.id
JOIN Community ON Codes.community_id = Community.id
JOIN Votes ON Votes.votable_id = Codes.community_id AND Votes.voter_id = Codes.user_id
WHERE vote_flag = 1
ORDER BY USERS.active_at ASC
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Does it still work there are more than 2 matching records that are being used ON condition?

Comment: Ow, sorry that's a typo, it should be `=` instead of `ON`.. Yes, you can have more than 2 conditions in `ON` clause.